# Tablet build slowly gallery images in high resolution

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have app only html and Im displaying high resolution images(over 1000px x 1000px) in a gallery image and take long time to load everything(overly 40+ images) and they are in my own image folder app, and by mean that, image by image is loading very slowly. There is any way to show something before and loading everything in the background and when it finish it show the gallery image? Something like, show splash screen while everything is begin to load thoses high resolution images and when it finished, it show my gallery image.

edit:the gallery take long time to load with the images that begin to build.
edit2:title

Answer (score 0):

I've created a JSFiddle with an image preloading script I use regularly. In the example I'm loading a few large images from Flickr, once they're loaded, the spinning gif is replaced with loaded text.

** Note: This does use jQuery's load() function but could be easily converted to native JS.

```
var preLoadImages = function (files, callback) {
    var i, img, _count, _counter, _interval;
    _count = files.length;
    _counter = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (i < files.length) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = files[i];
        $(img).load(function () {
            return _counter++;
        });
        i++;
    }
    return _interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (_count === _counter) {
            clearInterval(_interval);
            return callback();
        }
    }, 50);
}
```

Hopefully this will help you accomplish your goal.

http://jsfiddle.net/CcVqs/

Comment: It didn't worked as intend for me, because thanks to you, the code you provided did what I wanted, but the image gallery takes long to build it entire with thumbnails.